# How to parse wit.ai response in python

Tags: python, parsing, wit.ai

This is a response i get from my wit.ai app using a python client.
All i want to do is extract:

1. intent value field.
2. The entity type.
3. The value field of the entity.

`{'msg_id': '0KqBWZaeY9qKeVvdv3n', '_text': 'what is the temperature', 'entities': {'on_off': [{'confidence': 0.98730879525862, 'value': 'on'}], 'intent': [{'confidence': 0.99846661176623, 'value': 'get_temperature'}]}}`

Please note that the message can be different each time. Hard-coding locations in the dictionary might not be a great idea.

`{'msg_id': '0GN7pJRwYincs2p7xCo', '_text': 'turn light 1 off', 'entities': {'number': [{'confidence': 1, 'value': 1, 'type': 'value'}], 'on_off' [{'confidence': 0.96433768880251, 'value': 'off'}], 'intent': [{'confidence': 0.99552821331643, 'value': 'lights'}]}}`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have this output stored in a variable, like so:

```
dictionary = {'msg_id': '0KqBWZaeY9qKeVvdv3n', '_text': 'what is the temperature', 'entities': {'on_off': [{'confidence': 0.98730879525862, 'value': 'on'}], 'intent': [{'confidence': 0.99846661176623, 'value': 'get_temperature'}]}}
```

Intent value would be here:

```
intentValue = dictionary['entities']['intent'][0]['value']
```

Entity value would be here:

```
entityValue = dictionary['entities']['on_off'][0]['value']
```

I don't understand what you mean by entity type.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  This is perfect! By entity type I mean 'on_off'. However, I have no realised that the message I receive can vary, and hard coding locations it not the best idea. Let me update the question. Thanks again.